# I Help and Advice on using Oledb for large excel Files

Tags: c#, buffer, oledb, oledbconnection

So I am new to Oledb and I a have project that requires me to grab data from an excel file using a Console Application. The excel file has around 500 columns and 55 rows. How could I possibly get data from columns past 255?

Comment: You need to use the ACE driver (not Jet) to get more than 255 columns and workbook need to be an xlsx.  Excel 2007 upgrade Excel to get more than the 255 columns which wasn't supported in Excel 2003 using Jet.

Comment: Look into OpenXml (it's a NuGet package) and avoid OleDb and the ACE driver.  It can read very large Excel files.  I have used for 4gb excel files with no issues.

Comment: thanks Jimmy I'll give it a shot. It looks more promising thanks

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted. Seems a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read columns 256 -> you just need to modify the Select statement. By default both the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 **and** the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 drivers will read from Column 1-255 (A->IU) but you can ask it to read the remaining columns by specifying them on the Select statement.

To read the next 255 columns and taking "Sheet1" as your sheet name you would specify...

```
Select * From [Sheet1$IV:SP]
```

This will work even if there aren't another 255 columns. It will simply return the next chunk of columns if there are 1...255 additional columns.

Incidentally, the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver will read **both** .xls and any variant of .xlsx, .xlsm etc without changing the extended properties from "Excel 12.0". There is no need to if...then...else the connection string depending on the file type.

The OLEDB driver is pretty good for the most part but it really does rely on well formed sheets. Mixed data types aren't handled terribly well and it does weird things if the first columns/rows are empty but aside from that it's fine. I use it a **lot**.