# tell me the that what is the maximum limit of OLEDB data reader to read excel file columns?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, datareader

Help me out to get all my columns there are 1000 of columns I want to retrieve. I want to retrieve all my fields, and when I export them then it works but not when importing.
it exports but does not imports.
is there any other way to do this please send code are check my code is there any problem.
After importing I'm inserting values into the label using a loop.

```
    try
                {
                    attachment = new OpenFileDialog();
                    //attachment.Filter = "Excel 97-2003 Workbook|*.xls|Excel Workbook|*.xlsx";
                    if (attachment.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        fileName = attachment.FileName;
                        FileName_textBox = fileName;
                    }
                    string name = "Detail";
                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName_textBox + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
                    con.Open();
                    OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + name + "$]", con);
    
                    OleDbDataReader oleDbDataReader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (oleDbDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
                        {
                            int j = Convert.ToInt32(labels[i].Text);
                            int p = Convert.ToInt32(oleDbDataReader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                            labels[i].Text = (j + p).ToString();
                        }
                    }
 }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
```

The Exception is that array is outside the bound. I tried everything but I could not solve this problem, Whenever I loop only for 255 value then it works correctly. Help, please. I have tried many times in every way that I can but the same exception came.

Answer (score 0):

I did an answer on this previously....

[Help and Advice on using Oledb for large excel Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500557/i-help-and-advice-on-using-oledb-for-large-excel-files/55517570#55517570)

To read the next 255 columns and taking "Sheet1" as your sheet name you would specify...

```
Select * From [Sheet1$IV:SP]
```

etc etc etc. Reading 1000's is a chore but not impossible

Comment: so it at a time we only can get 255 fields and then in next query we can get next 255 values. Is that what are saying?

Comment: thanks I have seen your reply and it looks useful I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Yes. That's it exactly.